# Alternative API for pgfgantt's ganttbar command

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, gantt

I would like to do Gantt chart in Latex thus I'm studying http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf, where I can do something like:

[image]

by doing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,vgrid,time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,time slot unit=month,x unit=10mm
]{2018-09}{2019-06}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname} \\

    \ganttbar{Task 1}{2018-09}{2018-10} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 2 - Do something}{2018-11}{2018-12} \\
    \ganttbar{Something else}{2019-01}{2019-02} \\
    \ganttbar{Another task}{2019-03}{2019-4}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

From programmers perspective is difficult to compare `ganttbat`'s dates. Would be easier to code like this:

```
\ganttbar{2018-09}{2018-10}{Task 1} \\
\ganttbar{2018-11}{2018-12}{Task 2 - Do something} \\
\ganttbar{2019-01}{2019-02}{Something else} \\
\ganttbar{2019-03}{2019-04}{Another task}
```

Would be difficult to have this?

I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\newcommand{\newganttbar}[3]{%
  \ganttbar{#3}{#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,vgrid,time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,time slot unit=month,x unit=10mm
]{2018-09}{2019-06}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname} \\
    \newganttbar{2018-09}{2018-10}{Task 1} \\
    \newganttbar{2018-11}{2018-12}{Task 2 - Do something} \\
    \newganttbar{2019-01}{2019-02}{Something else} \\
    \newganttbar{2019-03}{2019-04}{Another task}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

But tasks became shorter by 1 month:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\newcommand{\newganttbar}[3]{%
  \ganttbar{#3}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,vgrid,time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,time slot unit=month,x unit=10mm
]{2018-09}{2019-06}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname} \\
    \newganttbar{2018-09}{2018-10}{Task 1} \\
    \newganttbar{2018-11}{2018-12}{Task 2 - Do something} \\
    \newganttbar{2019-01}{2019-02}{Something else} \\
    \newganttbar{2019-03}{2019-04}{Another task}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost. Why tasks are shorter by 1 month?

Comment: There's 1 `#1` that should be a `#2` in your code there...

Comment: This is really a bit too simple since `\ganttbar` has an optional argument to pass TIkZ options to the bar. So your new version should allow that too.

Comment: It will be nice to have an answer addressing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Although providing a wrapper with the different syntax for individual commands will work, it won't really work in full generality, since the `pgfgantt` package allows you to define *new* elements dynamically. Because of this I would recommend making a copy of `pgfgantt.sty`, and rename it `mypgfgantt.sty`.  Put this into your local `texmf` folder, and make the following change to the code:

On line 1014 you will find the following definition:

```
\newcommand\@newganttchartelement@two[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname gantt#1\endcsname[4][]{%
    \gtt@chartelement[##1]{##2}{##3}{##4}{#1}%
  }%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname ganttlinked#1\endcsname[4][]{%
    \begingroup%
    \ganttset{##1}%
    \gtt@chartelement{##2}{##3}{##4}{#1}%
    \ganttlink{\gtt@lastelement}{\gtt@currentelement}%
    \endgroup%
  }%
  \@newganttchartelement@definekeys{#1}%
}
```

Change this to the following:

```
\newcommand\@newganttchartelement@two[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname gantt#1\endcsname[4][]{%
    \gtt@chartelement[##1]{##4}{##2}{##3}{#1}%
  }%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname ganttlinked#1\endcsname[4][]{%
    \begingroup%
    \ganttset{##1}%
    \gtt@chartelement{##4}{##2}{##3}{#1}%
    \ganttlink{\gtt@lastelement}{\gtt@currentelement}%
    \endgroup%
  }%
  \@newganttchartelement@definekeys{#1}%
}
```

Save the file, and now you can use the new syntax with every command that takes two dates and a task as arguments, both the predefined ones and any new ones you define using `\newganttchartelement`.

Here's your example with your new syntax. To show how the new version works with newly defined bars, I've created a new chart element `\ganttredbar` which also uses the same syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mypgfgantt}
\newganttchartelement{redbar}
{%
  bar/.style={shape=ganttbar, inner sep=0pt, draw, fill=red},%
  bar incomplete/.style={/pgfgantt/bar, fill=black!25},%
  bar label text=\strut#1,%
  bar label font=\normalsize,%
  bar label node/.style={%
    anchor=east, font=\ganttvalueof{bar label font}%
  },%
  bar inline label anchor=center,%
  bar inline label node/.style={%
    anchor=center, font=\ganttvalueof{bar label font}%
  },%
  bar progress label anchor=east,%
  bar progress label font=\scriptsize,%
  bar progress label node/.style={%
    anchor=west, font=\ganttvalueof{bar progress label font}%
  },%
  bar left shift=0,%
  bar right shift=0,%
  bar top shift=.3,%
  bar height=.4%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
hgrid,vgrid,time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,time slot unit=month,x unit=10mm
]{2018-09}{2019-06}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname} \\
    \ganttbar{2018-09}{2018-10}{Task 1} \\
    \ganttredbar{2018-11}{2018-12}{Task 2 - Do something}\\
    \ganttbar{2019-01}{2019-02}{Something else} \\
    \ganttredbar{2019-03}{2019-04}{Another task}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

When you use `mypgfgantt.sty` you will receive a warning saying

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `mypgfgantt',
           but the package provides `pgfgantt'.
```

This can be safely ignored, but if you want to make it go away, change the `\ProvidesPackage` command at the top of the file to say `\ProvidesPackage{mypgfgantt}`.